# Solving $y^2 = 1263465 + 144x$ for integers $x,y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I've thrown this equation up as part of some research I'm doing.

$$y^2 = 1263465 + 144x$$

I was hoping there is a quick way to solve this without stepping through all the values. The value I'm interested in is $x = 1579$, but other $x$ values satisfy for $y$ as well, although I'm not bothered about those. Am I right in thinking that factorising $1263465$ might simplify the problem somewhat?

Cheers

:)

Comment: Are you trying to find all integer solutions?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow a few guidelines.  In particular, you need to make your question clear. As @PeterWoolfitt asked, are you looking for all integer solutions, or for just some integer solutions, or are rational or irrational solutions acceptable?

Comment: Thanks marty, that helps greatly. Yes, I'm only interested in integer values, but 1579 in particular.

Answer (score 4):

First of all,
reduce 1263465 
mod 144,
so you then only have to solve
$y^2 = a+144x$
where $0 \le a < 144$.

Then look up "quadratic residues".

Comment: You can also simplify by $9$.

Comment: I did not do any computation. Lazy me. But this is a good point, in that you want a and 144 (or whatever they reduce to) to be relatively prime.